# Interp() Function Akima Plots Confidence/Error Terms

Tags: r, interpolation, confidence-interval

When using the interp() function in the Akima package to create a matrix of interpolations, to be used with filled.contour to create an Akima plot - How would one go about ascertaining the confidence of the interpolation? The attached picture is an example of what I am trying to achieve, I have my interpolated surface, but where does the error term originate in this example? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evZtm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The akima interpolation model is not a statistical model, its an interpolation, so there's no model for the variance which is what you'd need to get any measure of "confidence".

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying, perhaps I poorly phrased my question, I have updated it with an example of what I am intending to achieve.

Comment: The methods in the akima package **aren't statistical**. They don't have any concept of uncertainty. If you want to map spatially sampled data over a grid *with uncertainty* you need to use a model-based method, such as kriging.